# fs.mkdirSync returns with 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am attempting to create a directory and use that directory as a variable to extract files from zip/rar files.

the bit of code that causes an error is here...

```
   var fileZip = fileName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); 
   // Removes full path to get 'file.zip'
   console.log(fileZip);
   var tempFolder = fs.mkdirSync('./app/cache/' + fileZip); 
   // tempFolder Variable for loaded comic
   console.log('CREATE: ' + tempFolder + ' created, line 26');
```

console.log returns with `CREATE: undefined created, line 26`.  What is going wrong?  The directory is created where I want it to be, but it isn't being saved as the variable.

Is it possible that since some file names have spaces (ie `file name.zip`) that is causing the problem?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mkdirSync function always returns undefined. This is its behaviour. You need to use another mechanism to determine the path of the created directory afterwards.

Comment: So, I would need to define `var tempFolder = './app/cache/' + fileZip` in a variable, then`fs.mkdirSync(tempFolder)`?

Comment: Not entirely true, result is undefined if recursive option passed to function is false, or the first directory path created if recursive is true

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easier time, you can use the module mkdirp which is the same util, but recursive.

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

mkdirp('./your/path', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    else console.log('Success!')
});
```

If there are no errors, you might be able to assume that the path now exists